# Is possible hide the url and parameters without use session variables in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables

I want to know, if theres a way, and if you could write an example, because all post I see on internet are using session variables, and for personal reasons I dont like it.